# Pandas: Filtered property behaves like unfiltered

Tags: pandas, date, filter

I have `DT`, which is a *datetime64 Series*:

```
0       2019-12-12 18:43:00
1       2019-03-22 18:30:00
2                       NaT
3       2019-04-17 02:00:00
4       2009-03-15 18:00:00
5       2019-04-02 20:25:00
6       2019-05-01 11:00:00
7       2019-04-10 17:00:00
8       1973-07-14 22:00:00
9       2019-06-06 19:00:00
10      2019-06-18 21:00:00
11      2019-06-12 22:00:00
12      2019-06-11 22:00:00
13      2018-06-15 01:00:00
14      1999-08-15 02:30:00
                ...        
88110   2019-10-01 22:00:00
88111   2019-10-01 22:45:00
88112   2019-10-02 01:00:00
88113   2019-10-02 03:26:00
88114   2019-10-02 03:26:00
88115   2019-10-02 05:33:00
88116   2019-10-02 06:35:00
88117   2019-10-02 12:00:00
88118   2019-10-02 19:00:00
88119   2019-10-02 19:15:00
88120   2019-10-02 20:00:00
88121   2019-10-02 20:00:00
88122   2019-10-02 20:03:00
88123   2019-10-02 22:00:00
88124   2019-10-02 22:00:00
Name: date_time, Length: 88125, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

and a piece of code:

```
DT[DT.between("2019-12-05", "2019-12-08") & DT.dt.weekday == 1].dt.weekday.value_counts()
```

which yields:

```
5    27
3    23
4    19
Name: date_time, dtype: int64
```

which includes 3, 4 and 5 days but not a single requested day 1!

So, when I code just:

```
DT[DT.between("2019-12-05", "2019-12-08")].dt.weekday
```

it yields:

```
3821     3
87138    3
87139    3
87140    3
87141    3
        ..
87328    5
87329    5
87330    5
87331    5
87332    5
```

which is logical because we have 3 days interval, which corresponds to 3 week days. And yes, we do not have week day 1 at all in our days range! So why does this `& DT.dt.weekday == 1` filter not work?

Thank you a lot for your time!

**UPDATE**

When I try to use any other filter like `& DT.dt.weekday == 2`, `& DT.dt.weekday == 3` etc., I get an empty *Series* as a result of the filtering like this:

```
DT[DT.between("2019-12-05", "2019-12-08") & DT.dt.weekday == 4]
```

Moreover, `DT.dt.weekday == 1` returns normal *True/False* list!

Maybe, we cannot filter by `dt.(...)` parameters?

Comment: Are you able to share a small subset of your data?

Comment: @Sala Just now added DT to the beginning! Thanks for your attention!

Comment: @Sala Found the answer! Operation order matters! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this:

```
DT[DT.between("2019-12-05", "2019-12-08") & DT.dt.weekday == 1]
```

is performed as this:

```
DT[ (DT.between("2019-12-05", "2019-12-08") & DT.dt.weekday)   ==   1 ]
```

which is why DT.dt.weekday the filter returned *True* for each day between *2019-12-05* and *-08* because `& DT.dt.weekday` never really influenced as it was *3* to *5* for all the mentioned days range.

So, when I coded it like this:

```
DT[ (DT.between("2019-12-05", "2019-12-08")) & (DT.dt.weekday == 1) ]
```

everything worked out as was expected, i.e. nothing was chosen. But this, on the other hand:

```
DT[ (DT.between("2019-12-05", "2019-12-08")) & (DT.dt.weekday == 3) ]
```

yielded resulted in a few lines corresponding to day 3.

So, once parentheses are correctly put to separate `A` and `B` statements in `A & B`  filtering expression, everything works as designed!

Thank you all for your time anyway! =)